# How can I find which Samba user has a file locked?

Tags: macos, server.app, smb

I have a user who often can't delete files in an SMB share on a Mac server (MacOS 10.13.6), because the client (MacOS 10.15.7) shows:
"the operation cannot be completed because a required item is in use"

- lsof on the client does not show the file as being open.
- lsof on the server shows the file is being used by the smbd process,
  and the process ID, which is the same for all other SMB connections.

How can I pinpoint what SMB client computer/user is accessing the file?